# PHP array returning the same value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm stuck on this and I'm not actually seeing where exactly the problem is.

I have a bunch of input tags which are placed like that:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Material 1</label>
    <input hidden="hidden" name="idMaterial[]" value="13" type="text" />
    <input class="form-control" name="total[]" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Material 2</label>
    <input hidden="hidden" name="idMaterial[]" value="8" type="text" />
    <input class="form-control" name="total[]" type="text" />
</div>
```

I have 20 input like that, the idea here is that if I write 10 in the Material 1's input field, my DB would receice something like:

```
id         => A.I
idMaterial => 13
total      => 10
```

But once I run the code, it comes like that (repeating the idMaterial, even if I write in more than 1 input. It always repeat the first):

```
idMaterial: 13
total: 10

idMaterial: 13
total: 20
```

That's the code I'm using to receive that form:

```
$idMaterial = array();
$total  = array();

if($this->input->post('total')){
    foreach($this->input->post('idMaterial') as $row){
        $idMaterial = $row;

        foreach($this->input->post('total') as $row2){
            $total  = $row2;

            echo 'Material: '. $idMaterial .'<br> Total: '. $total. '<br><br>'; // TESTING THE OUTPUT
            $query = $this->pedido->salvaLabMaterial($total, $idMaterial); // I'M SENDING THE DATA TO MODEL HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips is very welcome.

Comment: Your loops are nested so you are not going to get the results you want.  To do this correctly you are going to want to actually set the key value in your input names ie `idMaterial[1]` and `total[1]` this way you can reference the related total by key name.  You then instead of doing a for each to get the matching total you say `$_POST['total'][$matching_key]`

Comment: Considering that I won't necessary use all the input, e.g. in some jobs I would fill just 2 out of the 20. Saying that, I would like only to receive these 2 instead of receiving the other 18 input fields as null. Would i be able to reach that only by this?

Answer (score 0):

@RiggsFolly

That's where I'm sending the posts the way it comes from the HTML form as you said:

```
$query = $this->pedido->salvaLabMaterial($this->input->post('total'), 
                                         $this->input->post('idMaterial'), 
                                        );
```

The model:

```
public function salvaLabMaterial($this->input->post('idMaterial'), $this->input->post('total')){

    $query = $this->db->query(" insert into labpedidomaterial (idMaterial, total) values ('".$this->input->post('idMaterial')."', '".$this->input->post('total')."') ");

}
```

Comment: There are to many things wrong with your logic here. A proper answer would involve pretty much a complete training course in programming, so i have deleted my answer.